# Make cumulative sum in view oracle

Tags: oracle, view

I want to make a view in oracle, how can I get value of 'saldo' that I supposed like in this screenshoot with oracle? can someone give me the script?

The result that I want:

```
dateacct   period_id   startdate   enddate     debit   credit   saldo
7/10/2015     1        1/10/2015   30/10/2015   25       0        25
8/10/2015     1        1/10/2015   30/10/2015   0        5        20
9/10/2015     1        1/10/2015   30/10/2015   0        3        17
10/10/2015    1        1/10/2015   30/10/2015   4        0        21
```

Notes: dateacct,period_id,startdate,enddate,credit,debit are the column that I take from 'akun' table.

Comment: Search for "cumulative sum"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEACCT, PERIOD_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, CREDIT, DEBIT,
    SUM (DEBIT-CREDIT) OVER (ORDER BY DATEACCT,PERIOD_ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) saldo
from AKUN
ORDER BY DATEACCT, PERIOD_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a bunch of things you can do with Oracle Analytics functions, especially made for that purpose.

[Oracle Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

You can also use the `PARTITION BY` to have cumul for the day or the period:

```
SELECT DATEACCT, PERIOD_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, CREDIT, DEBIT,  
    SUM (DEBIT-CREDIT) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEACCT ORDER BY DATEACCT,PERIOD_ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) CUMULDAY,
    SUM (DEBIT-CREDIT) OVER (PARTITION BY PERIOD_ID ORDER BY DATEACCT,PERIOD_ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) CUMULPERIOD
from AKUN
ORDER BY DATEACCT, PERIOD_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE;



DATEACCT  PERIOD_ID STARTDATE ENDDATE      CREDIT      DEBIT   CUMULDAY    CUMULPERIOD
-------- ---------- --------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
07/10/15          1 01/10/15  30/10/15          0         25         25          25 
08/10/15          1 01/10/15  30/10/15          5          0         -5          20 
09/10/15          1 01/10/15  30/10/15          3          0         -3          17 
10/10/15          1 01/10/15  30/10/15          0          4          4          21
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I got it