# Write logic for adjusting values from a table based on FIFO in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

**Table name – Fin_mst_T_voucher_hdr, Fin_mst_T_voucher_det**

**table_01: Header is having**

Voucher_Code

Voucher_date

**table_02: Details**

Voucher_Code

Account_code

Entry_type – Debit/Credit

Amount

Take the sum of Credit values for a particular account and adjust those values against debit values based on the FIFO method (Date in ascending order)

Here is my logic:

```
create or replace procedure adjust_value (Voucher in number)
is 
v_credit number;
v_dedit number;
v_total number;
begin

select sum(credit) into v_credit from voucher
where voucher_id = Voucher;

for a in (select sum(debit) into v_dedit from voucher where voucher_id = Voucher order by date)

v_total:= v_credit - v_debit;

exception
   when no_data_found then
        v_total:=0;
end;
```

Comment: I suggest adding sample data for both tables, just enough to get the point across.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a cumulative sum based on date order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646514/make-cumulative-sum-in-view-oracle